# How often are Audience Manager Claims loaded into the ADF and are they cached in storage layer?

Tags: 2013, audience-manager, ambient-data-framework

When the Audience Manager ADF Cartridge is configured in my web application, does it load data from the subscription database on every request, or do the claims have a session scope? Additionally, does the storage layer contain caching for Contact and Segment data? If so how  is this invalidated? Finally, if claims have session scope, but contact data was updated (either front-end or back-end) during a session, what would be the best way of making sure that the claims in the ADF are in sync?

Answer (score 5):

The Contact data is loaded anew on every request. There's no caching involved.

That makes it simple, if not the most optimal in terms of resources.